# What is wrong with the following VBA code for Excel macros?

Tags: excel, vba

The following code is VBA code for an Excel macros. The objective is to read input from the file `Impeller_hub.dat` and to write it into `copy_hub.dat`. The error message I received stated that there's a type mismatch, Run-time error '13'. Where is the error and how can it be rectified?

```
Private Sub fn_write_to_text_Click()
   Dim FilePath As String
   Dim CellData As String
   Dim LastCol As Long
   Dim LastRow As Long

   Dim fso As FileSystemObject
   Set fso = New FileSystemObject
   Dim stream As TextStream
   Dim stream2 As String

   LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
   LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    stream2 = "C:\Users\devanandd\Desktop\copy_hub.dat"

   Set stream = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\devanandd\Desktop\Files\NUMECA\Impeller_Hub.dat", stream2, True)

   CellData = ""

   For i = 1 To LastRow
      For j = 1 To LastCol
         CellData = Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value)
         stream.WriteLine "The Value at location (" & i & "," & j & ")" & CellData
      Next j
   Next i

   stream.Close
   MsgBox ("Job Done")
End Sub
```

Comment: Any clue *where* there error is occurring?

Comment: You should have a look into the [OpenTextFile Method Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265347(v=vs.60).aspx) you are using it the wrong way.

Comment: You pass a string (stream2) as the 2nd argument to OpenTextFile() - this is not valid.

Comment: @Alex K So what is the correct datatype of the argument?

Comment: The second parameter should be either `ForAppending`, `ForReading`, or `ForWriting`

Comment: Your question suggests you want to read from the Impeller_Hub.dat file, yet your code appears to be reading every cell from the' ActiveSheet' and writing a line for each one. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this works for me (using as much from your code as possible):

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

Private Sub fn_write_to_text_Click()

    Dim FilePath        As String
    Dim CellData        As String
    Dim LastCol         As Long
    Dim LastRow         As Long

    Dim fso             As Object
    Dim stream          As Object
    Dim stream2         As String

    Dim i               As Long
    Dim j               As Long

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    stream2 = "C:\YOURPATH\Desktop\aaa.txt"

    'Uncomment the next line if you do not have the file
    'Set stream = fso.CreateTextFile(stream2, True)
    Set stream = fso.OpenTextFile(stream2, 8) '8 is ForAppending

    CellData = ""

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        For j = 1 To LastCol
            CellData = Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).value)
            stream.WriteLine "The Value at location (" & i & "," & j & ")" & CellData
        Next j
    Next i

    stream.Close
    MsgBox ("Job Done")

End Sub
```

The code below would work if you have the file `aaa.txt` on your desktop. If you do not have it write:

`Set stream = fso.CreateTextFile(stream2, True)` to create it and delete the line `Set stream = fso.OpenTextFile(stream2,8)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read from file `Impeller_hub.dat` and to write to file `copy_hub.dat`, then you need two `TextStream` variables, and two separate calls of `fso.OpenTextFile`: one with second argument `ForReading`, the other with second argument `ForWriting`.

Or, if you want to add data to the end of file `Impeller_hub.dat`, then - as CLR already wrote - the second argument for `fso.OpenTextFile` should be `ForAppending`.